# How to get client assemblies within a Non SharePoint Machine?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, client-object-model, csom

I am running CSOM code in PowerShell to access data of SharePoint 2013 sites. I am adding below lines to load the DLLs in my machine. These lines expect these DLLs to be present in this location.

```
Add-Type –Path "C:\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type –Path "C:\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
```

If i have to run the same script from other server, how i can ensure these DLLs will be present in that location as we cant download and save these in C:\ path every time. Is there any way that these will be accessed from some CDN or online link?

Answer (score 2):

**Download proper version and install in your target server.**

- [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)
- [SharePoint Server 2016 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51679)
- [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Comment: Then how to refer that in our script?

Comment: Default install path C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15 or 16\ISAPI